# Options on programing STM32 with another microcontroller

Tags: stm32, esp8266, ota

I'm going to use STM32f103 as a main microcontroller and ESP8266 as a Wi-Fi module in my project. These 2 chips are in contact with each other via UART.

I have a server that contains the "version2.bin" file. I can download this file with ESP8266 but how should I update STM32 firmware with this file?

In other words, how can I perform OTA?

Comment: For STM32, I'm using Keil IDE and for ESP8266, I'm using Arduino. I don't have any SD card in this project and for the sake of price, I'm not allowed to have one, So I'm looking for another option. I think ESP12-F has enough memory for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

- STM32F1 have an embedded bootloader you can use through uart. Details are here: [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and here [AN3155](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00264342-usart-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
- You can make your own: Partition your flash and save one part for the bootloader and one for the application. The former should check for some signal to update the latter. Afterwards the bootloader should jump to the application.
- In theory you can program also by using the debugger protocol but never saw it done, I suppose it's simply insane to do that this way.